# Импорт файла с хранимой процедурой в существующую базу

Tags: sql-server, импорт

У меня есть база в Microsoft SQL Server. Мне скинули файл с хранимой процедурой. Как я его могу добавить к себе в базу данных? Пытался выполнить содержимое файла, но получаю ошибку. Ниже приведены примеры ошибки и часть текста процедуры

> Invalid object name 'dbo.unefficient_block'.

```
USE [rum]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[unefficient_block]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @calls int
DECLARE @msisdn nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @status int
DECLARE @warn_sms int
declare @lang int

declare cur1  CURSOR FOR 
select nds, count(*) as calls 
from rum.dbo.unefficient_calls
where nds not in (select phone from rum.dbo.huly h) 
-- and nds not in (select msisdn COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS from rum.dbo.unefficient_status s where status=1) 
group by nds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[unefficient_block]
```

на

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[unefficient_block]
```

`ALTER` изменяет существующий объект. Т.к. в вашей базе не было процедуры `[dbo].[unefficient_block]`, вам нужно её не изменять, а создать с помощью `CREATE`.

Comment: Спасибо! процедура создана!)  Но почему- то все еще подчеркивает [dbo].[unefficient_block]  красным и пишет invalid object name ?

Comment: @Евгений _"подчёркивает"_ - это в SqlServer Management Studio ? Там в настройках есть обновить кэш: Edit->Intellisence->Refresh Local Cache (Ctrl + Shift + R)

Comment: Да в ней. Прости, за глупые вопросы)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)